# array of objects no updates and properties are not read

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to update an array containing objects. I have consition, that if Select_Item property is not equal to Item property in Cart_Item, then a new object is pushed in Cart_Item array.

If it is equal then I need to update the Cart_Item object. The update part of the code is not working and also could not read the properties in Cart_Item. The relevant code is below

```
if (this.state.Item !== this.state.Select_Item) {
      let yy = [...(this.state.Cart_Item || [])];
      let xx = {
        Price: ll,
        Item: ll3,
        Quantity: this.state.Select_Quantity,
        Total_Item_Price: ll6
      };
      yy.push(xx);
      this.setState({ Cart_Item: yy });
    } else {
      //Cart updata and add objects
      // let Cart_Item = this.state.Cart_Item;
     
      let Cart_Item = [...(this.state.Cart_Item || [])];
      var index = Cart_Item.findIndex(
        obj => obj.Item === this.state.Select_Item
      );
      Cart_Item[index].Price= ll;
      Cart_Item[index].Item = ll3;
      Cart_Item[index].Quantity = this.state.Select_Quantity;
      Cart_Item[index].Total_Item_Price = ll6;
      this.setState({ Cart_Item });
    }

    console.log(this.state.Cart_Item);
```

Also please see sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-meninsky-hhf1g

Comment: Just a side comment: I would suggest changing your `Cart_Item` name to something that actually represents an array: `Cart_Items` or `Cart_List`, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things that could be better on your code. In the first part of the "if statement", you are using the `spread` operator, which is nice to avoid mutation. But then you do a `.push` in the array, which mutates your variable

You also don't need an "or" (`|| []`) to fall back to an empty array when you are spreading.

Your updated code (for the first part) could be like this:

```
const updatedCartItem = [
  ...this.state.Cart_Item,
  {
    Price: ll,
    Item: ll3,
    Quantity: this.state.Select_Quantity,
    Total_Item_Price: ll6
  }
]
this.setState({ Cart_Item: updatedCartItem });
```

For the "else statement", you are also mixing `spread` with mutation. When you need to change item(s) in an array, one option to avoid mutation is to use the `.map` function ([more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)).

In short, `.map` will iterate your array and modify specific items. You also don't have a check to make sure you did find the index of the cart item that you want to update.

With those fixes, your "else statement" could be like this:

```
const updatedCartItem = this.state.Cart_Item.map((item) => {
  if (item === this.state.Select_Item) {
    // If item found, returns a new object (no mutation) with updated attributes
    return {
      Price: ll,
      Item: ll3,
      Quantity: this.state.Select_Quantity,
      Total_Item_Price: ll6
    }
  }

  // If item not found, just return the current item as it is.
  // This is to make sure you are not removing items from your original array.
  return item
})
this.setState({ Cart_Item: updatedCartItem });
```

---

All together:

```
if (this.state.Item !== this.state.Select_Item) {
  const updatedCartItem = [
    ...this.state.Cart_Item,
    {
      Price: ll,
      Item: ll3,
      Quantity: this.state.Select_Quantity,
      Total_Item_Price: ll6
    }
  ]
  this.setState({ Cart_Item: updatedCartItem });
} else {
  const updatedCartItem = this.state.Cart_Item.map((item) => {
    if (item === this.state.Select_Item) {
      // If item found, returns a new object (no mutation) with updated attributes
      return {
        Price: ll,
        Item: ll3,
        Quantity: this.state.Select_Quantity,
        Total_Item_Price: ll6
      }
    }

    // If item not found, just return the current item as it is.
    // This is to make sure you are not removing items from your original array.
    return item
  })
  this.setState({ Cart_Item: updatedCartItem });
}
```

Comment: thanks Bruno. This helps a lot. But i think we got issue, as there are two errors, one cannot read map  property and the second is "Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance"

Comment: This means that `Cart_Item` is not an `array`. If you are not doing it yet, you should put an initial state of an empty array for that variable `[]`. If you already do that, could you update the question to include more parts of your code? Thanks

Comment: This is actually a weird error... I assumed you would only go inside this "if" condition if your Cart is **not** empty...

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I cannot set initial state as empty array, because i need to update the items as well in it. This is the final Cart item , so it can always change.

Comment: Bruno, it says cannot read property map. please sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-lamport-k4n5z

Comment: You can add an initial empty state, that will not break your code and is a good practice, so it is easy to understand your component state :)
I updated this sandbox to show you that. I also had to fix other issues you had, for example your if was wrong, since was trying to compare a `this.state.Item` which is never a state, since `Item` is a property of your `Cart_Item` object. Take a look and, if needed, feel free to open a new SO post with new questions: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-black-5y3fk

Comment: Bruno thank you. It is working just fine. but i am new inprogramming. Can you please explain more. 1.Why this.state.item is not considered state 2.!itemFound it should be adding new object , is it really updating? 3. what is itemFound=false tells? 4. Also i still could not know which line of code is actually updating? Sorry to ask so many questions. But i am stuck to this problem for 2 weeks. I do not want to loose this opportunity.